# Display a view for few seconds (custom push from NavController)

Tags: xcode, view, swift, push, navigationcontroller

I started with Master-Detail Application. Now I try to add a custom View (default UIViewController with simple Label) which will be displayed for some seconds (like a loading view) before detail/master views will be accessible.

My Problem now is that if I add my ViewController to AppDelegate and push to it from NavigationController i get an empty view.
See here:
[image]

I didn't change anything but adding just one line of code to appdelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as UINavigationController
    let controller = masterNavigationController.topViewController as MasterViewController
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext

    // +++ Custom ViewController is to be displayed from here +++

    navigationController.pushViewController(ViewController(), animated: true)

    return true
}
```

I do not get where the problem is...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line in your code

```
navigationController.pushViewController(ViewController(), animated: true)
```

you are instantiating a new, empty view controller, whis is probably not what you want.

Get a reference to your storyboard (i.e from your masterviewcontroller) to create the view controller and push this one on the navigation stack. Example:

```
if let myVC = controller.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(...) {
    navigationController.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
}
```